# How to read all pdf pages in PyQt?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I click pilihfile pushbutton to select a pdf file and display its content on textEdit_2. The pdf I chose has 3 pages, but it only show its last page. What should i fix for looping?

```
def pilihfile(self):
    files, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(None, "Open File", "", "PDF Files (*.pdf)")
    file_name = str(files))

    pdf_document = file_name
    self.textEdit.setText(pdf_document)
    doc = fitz.open(pdf_document)
    hal = doc.pageCount

    for i in range (hal):
        page = doc.loadPage(i)
        page1text = page.get_text().strip()
        self.textEdit_2.setPlainText(page1text)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that [`setPlainText()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#setPlainText) method replaces the old text with the new text provided, instead it uses [`append()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#append) method which appends the text:

```py
self.textEdit_2.append(page1text)
```